# how to get json key name from the result in php?

Tags: php, json

I want to the key or reference_id detail (as both are same value) when the art_ean value contains 400004471.

```
{
    "TD0000000000993": {
        "reference_id": "TD0000000000993",
        "art_ean": "400004481|,400004491|,400004471|"
    },
    "TD0000000000992": {
        "reference_id": "TD0000000000992",
        "art_ean": "400004482|,400004492|,400004472|"
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I have tried..."_ - Please include your attempts, the expected result and what result you're currently getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `json` is not valid. You should remove the last `,` on each object. You can use a list to have some more details https://jsonlint.com.

Here is what I believe that you want.

```
<?php

$data = '{
    "TD0000000000993": {
        "reference_id": "TD0000000000993",
        "art_ean": "400004481|,400004491|,400004471|"
    },
    "TD0000000000992": {
        "reference_id": "TD0000000000992",
        "art_ean": "400004482|,400004492|,400004472|"
    }
}';

$decodedData = \json_decode($data, true);

$result = array_column(
    array_filter($decodedData, function($data) {
        return false !== strpos($data['art_ean'], '400004471');
    }),
    'reference_id'
);
```

Comment: Error1: This is the error am getting Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in 

Error2: Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Comment: Hereby the link so you can copy paste correctly. I ran it on all the versions since 5.2 and it runs OK https://3v4l.org/i8gKk

Comment: I know what is happening. You didn't fix you json as I told you to do. See the difference between mine and yours. Copy paste your current json on https://jsonlint.com and click on validate to see the error with the `trailing comma`. Please, read my answers before try it.

Comment: I corrected the comma issue.
Warning: Illegal string offset 'art_ean' in----- 2)


Notice: Undefined index: art_ean in

Comment: `Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string` you should pass the json string to `json_decode` not an object.

Comment: I Corrected it. Please find my previsous warning messages.

Comment: Get the raw data "string representation", like I did on the example, and pass it to the `json_decode()`. You can see the documentation for this function here http://php.net/json_decode. Also, did you tried to run my code in alone or you tried to adjust it to your case without even run it? Because you said my example didn't work, when actually it seems like you don't know how to apply it to your case. May you clarify that please?

Comment: I updated the code to get only the `reference_id` check it again. As for the illegal offset, check if you always have in your json the key `art_ean`. Because it seems to not exists for some records. You questions it really incomplete. I don't know if I can help you further.

Comment: Am getting the result thank you. when i echo the result the result appear like ["TD0000000000993"]. Kindly tell me how to echo the value without the quote and brackets. thanks in advance.